# What is the 'H' in 'RWH' for register access type in mcu register map?

Tags: embedded, peripheral

In the [EFM32 Ref Manual](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/reference-manuals/EFM32ZG-RM.pdf), on pg 256, there are some registers in the timer peripheral's register map that have an access type of 'RWH'.

I understand that **R** and **W** mean **Read** and **Write**, but what does **H** symbolize? I can't seem to find anything in the manual or on google.

Comment: Page 3: "RWH - Readable, writable and updated by hardware."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Write** top value before calibration.

**Read** calibration result from this register **when Calibration Ready flag has been set.**  updated by ***Hardware***